# Exporting Dataframe to Oracle: TypeError

Tags: python, sql, oracle, pandas, cx-oracle

I am repeatedly failing to export the following Dataframe to my Oracle table:

```
final df is:    S USTAINABLE H ARVEST S ECTOR| QUOTA LISTING JUN 11 2013 Unnamed: 1  \
2                                              6/4/13           130196   
3                                             5/28/13           130158   
4                                              6/4/13           130210   
5                                             5/14/13           130079   
6                                              6/4/13           130187   
7                                              6/4/13           130208   
8                                             6/11/13           130249   
9                                              6/4/13           130204   
10                                            5/28/13           130148   
11                                            5/28/13           130149   
12                                            5/28/13           130157   
13                                            5/21/13           130105   
14                                            5/21/13           130106   
15                                             6/4/13           130205   
16                                            6/11/13           130250   
17                                             6/4/13           130206   
18                                            6/11/13           130248   
19                                       QUOTA TO BUY                0   
20                                               DATE         TRADE ID   
21                                            6/11/13           130239   
22                                            5/14/13           130074   
23                                            3/26/13           130006   
24                                            5/14/13           130075   
25                                             5/7/13           130023   
26                                            5/14/13           130039   
27                                                  1                0   

        Unnamed: 2     Unnamed: 3 Unnamed: 4  email_year  email_month  \
2          COD GBW          10000        0.6        2013            6   
3          COD GBW            300        0.6        2013            6   
4      HADDOCK GBE   UP TO 30,000     OFFERS        2013            6   
5           PLAICE           1000       0.45        2013            6   
6       WHITE HAKE   UP TO 25,000        0.5        2013            6   
7       WHITE HAKE           4000        0.5        2013            6   
8        WINTER GB           3300       0.25        2013            6   
9        WINTER GB          10000       0.48        2013            6   
10       WINTER GB   1U0P 0T,0O00       0.25        2013            6   
11       WINTER GB   UP TO 10,000        0.4        2013            6   
12       WINTER GB           1400       0.25        2013            6   
13       WINTER GB          10000        0.5        2013            6   
14       WINTER GB          10000        0.5        2013            6   
15      WINTER GOM           1000       0.38        2013            6   
16      WINTER SNE           6500        0.4        2013            6   
17      WINTER SNE           3000       0.63        2013            6   
18  YELLOWTAIL GOM           2000       1.25        2013            6   
19               0              0          0        2013            6   
20   DESIRED STOCK         AMOUNT  BUY PRICE        2013            6   
21         COD GOM   UP TO 14,000        2.1        2013            6   
22         COD GOM          20000    INQUIRE        2013            6   
23         COD GBE            ANY        1.5        2013            6   
24     HADDOCK GOM          10000    INQUIRE        2013            6   
25     HADDOCK GOM    UP TO 6,000       0.75        2013            6   
26      WHITE HAKE  UP TO 100,000        0.3        2013            6   
27               0              0          0        2013            6   

    email_day  
2          11  
3          11  
4          11  
5          11  
6          11  
7          11  
8          11  
9          11  
10         11  
11         11  
12         11  
13         11  
14         11  
15         11  
16         11  
17         11  
18         11  
19         11  
20         11  
21         11  
22         11  
23         11  
24         11  
25         11  
26         11  
27         11
```

It fails on the line `cursor.executemany(sql_query, exported_data)` with the error

`TypeError: expecting numeric data`.

My relevant code:

```
cursor = con.cursor()
exported_data = [tuple(x) for x in df.values]
#exported_data = [str(x) for x in df.values]

sql_query = ("INSERT INTO ROUGHTABLE(species, date_posted, stock_id, pounds, money, trade_year, trade_month, trade_day, sector_name, ask)" "VALUES(:3, :1, :2, :4, :5, :6, :7, :8 'Sustainable Harvest Sector', '1')")

cursor.executemany(sql_query, exported_data)
con.commit() #commit to database

cursor.close()
con.close()
```

When I comment the `exported_data` line and un-comment the one below it, it still fails, but this time with the error

`cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number`

Researching these errors reveal that they could be due to bind variables, invalid date formats, trying to export a string vs a dict, etc. I am not an expert with SQL and would like help solving this.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing a comma.
It looks --- VALUES(:3, :1, :2, :4, :5, :6, :7, :8 'Sustainable Harvest Sector', '1')")

Try---

sql_query = ("INSERT INTO ROUGHTABLE(species, date_posted, stock_id, pounds, money, trade_year, trade_month, trade_day, sector_name, ask) VALUES(:3, :1, :2, :4, :5, :6, :7, :8, 'Sustainable Harvest Sector', '1')")

Oracle sql--- insert into  (col_1,col_2) values ('character_value',numeric_val);

Sql_query=("insert into  (col_1,col_2) values ('character_value',numeric_val);")

Comment: I fixed that but it still fails with the same error :(

Comment: Did you also remove the extra quotes you put in your code between 'ask' and VALUES? i.e., instead of [... sector_name, ask)" "VALUES(:3, :1 ...]   it should be [... sector_name, ask) VALUES(:3, :1, ...]

Comment: I agree with @WillJobs. Syntactically, your query is invalid with those double quote pairs in middle between `INSERT` and `VALUES`.

Comment: Those extra quotes have never messed it up in the past. I removed them and it still failed though

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are non-numeric values in what looks like numeric columns, no?  Adding the oracle table definition could assist as to where the issue is.

Comment: All the columns in my Oracle table are set to receive `VarChar2` so it's not that the column is looking for a number but receiving a letter.